# Unable to add or retrieve results

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase web SDK, as my project is still on expo

I can't seem to add or get any results from firestore. No error is thrown, nothing is shown, nothing is saved also.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'

var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = firebase.firestore();

var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

var setAda = docRef.set({
    first: 'Ada',
    last: 'Lovelace',
    born: 1815
})
```

anyone having the same issue? someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution which work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that is **compatible with Expo** just run:

```
npm i -S firebase @firebase/firestore
```

and add to your code

```
import  * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
```

now you can use

```
firebase.firestore()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), it is the officially recommended React Native library for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: are you using it with expo?

Comment: No, expo can work only with web sdk, and web sdk not work with react native and firestore

Comment: Question is about use with 'expo' and how to get it to work with rn and firestore.  It doesn't currently work with firstore, but it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/283

It is ascribed to the closure library used by fb web sdk.

They haven't decided what the right permanent fix is (they started thinking it could be fixed via a change to closure but are now looking for a fix in react-native) but patches to the FB web SDK code are provided that serve as a temporary solution.